# Python, tkinter: How to select a directory then load the path as a variable to an imported class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing a gui in which the user has to browse choose the a directory. Then I need the directory path to be saved as a variable and used by an imported class.

So far I have written the code that enables a user to pick a directory but am not stuck as what to do next. The code I have so far is below:

```
def loadDirectory():
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

the function is called by pushing a button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one knows what you want to do next too, because you never said what you wanted. You already solved the problem mentioned.

Comment: i need to use the value of "directory" in a class so other functions within the class can be called

Comment: Go ahead and use it then. Return the value and put it somewhere.

Comment: i would, except i don't now how...

Comment: Are you importing a class, and you want to use it in that?

Comment: yeah, the class is called chrome

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple.

```
import chrome

def loadDirectory():
    chrome.directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: That happens to the best of us.

Comment: when i try and call functions from the chrome class it says that self isnt defined. in the class init function i have the directory as self.directory. Hope you understand if not i can put some of the class code in the question

Comment: Please, post the whole code and the error log. Otherwise it is simply impossible to know what you are talking about. If you want specific help, post a specific/detailed question. Thanks.

Comment: @LWH91 Don't use `self`. `self` is automatically inserted.